# Grafana User Growth Time Series with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series, grafana

I'm trying display the user growth per day using Grafana Time Series with SQL Server. However I found the documentation to be unhelpful and my queries are incorrect.

The following returns a constant value of 1 for every day. What do I need to change to display the number of new users created per day?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
SELECT 
  $__timeGroup([created_at],'1d') as time, 
  COUNT(id) as value, 
  'users' as metric
FROM [db].[user]
WHERE $__timeFilter([created_at])
GROUP BY [created_at]
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SELECT
  $__timeGroup(created_at, '1d') AS time,
  COUNT(id) as 'New Users'
FROM [db].[user]
GROUP BY $__timeGroup(created_at, '1d')
ORDER BY 1
```